# AWS glue: crawler does not identify metadata when CSV contains string and timestamp/date values

Tags: csv, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have come across one thing when we consider CSV as input to crawler

1. crawler doesn't identify the columns header when all the data is in string format in CSV.

> #P1 Headers are displayed as col0,col1...colN.
> #P2 And actual column names are considered as data.
> #P3 Metadata (i.e. column datatype is shown as string even the CSV dataset consists of date/timestamp value)

2. If we are going to consider custom (CSV) classifier then we are manually mentioning the column header.

> #P2 will get covered i.e. column names will be removed however
> #P1 still remain same. column header will be displayed as col0,col1...colN.

There are 3 things I want to avoid and achieve expected result.

1. CSV with strings only should show actual column names instead of col0,col1...colN.
2. Metadata of generated table should show correctly (i.e. date/timestamp, string) once it is crawled by crawler.
3. If Custom classifier is used, we need to mention column header names manually in classifier, yet result is not satisfactory.
   Need generic solution instead of manual interventions.

Have gone through this document: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html)
If anyone has already implemented the solution, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution to one of the above points. Headers i.e. first line of CSV is displayed by using **'Has heading'** in CSV classifier.

However, Solution for following is yet to figure out.

1. Metadata of CSV file is shown as string even if column contains timestamp/date value. Crawler is reading these datatypes as string.
2. Custom classifier needs manual interventions. I have mentioned all column names in classifier. Is there generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

If we are using `pd.to_csv` to write the dataframe, then to avoid getting column names as `col1, col2` and so on, add the parameter
`index_label='index'` such as:

`pd.to_csv(df,index_label='index')`